# How to handle tapping local notification when app is terminated in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using **flutter_local_notifications** plugin to show notifications in Flutter and here is the initialization code:

```
Future<void> initializePlatformNotifications() async {
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('icon');

final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
    requestSoundPermission: true,
    requestBadgePermission: true,
    requestAlertPermission: true,
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
  android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
  iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    behaviorSubject.add(notificationResponse.payload!);
    
  },
  onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
);
```

}

the above code is working and the onDidReceiveNotificationResponse callback is called when the notification is clicked when the app is in the background but when the app is terminated and I click on the notification the callback is not called.

Should I use a different callback or my initialization code is missing something?

Comment: Can you take a look at this question I am facing issue when the app is on background [local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75068939/how-to-navigate-from-the-local-local-notification-from-the-background?noredirect=1#comment132474087_75068939)

Answer (score 4):

If your app is launched from terminated state by clicking on notification, you can get NotificationResponse via

```dart
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails()
```

`onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` only called when your app is paused, not terminated.