# How to navigate from the local local notification from the background?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process, flutter-local-notification

I am using flutter local notification in my application. I could not able to navigate to a specific page by clicking the local notification when the application is in background.

**It gives me the error:**

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart': Failed assertion: line 1018 pos 12: 'callback != null':           The backgroundHandler needs to be either a static function or a top 
      level function to be accessible as a Flutter entry point.)
```

This is my code:

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();



     Future<void> listiningToNotification() async {
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
      .listen((message) => notificationOnClick(message));
}

Future<void> localNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    "local_notification",
    message.data["booking_id"],
    description: message.data["task_id"],
    importance: Importance.max,
    playSound: true,
  );
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/notification_icon");
  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) => notificationOnClick(message),
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: (details) =>
        firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,
  );
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              importance: channel.importance,
              playSound: channel.playSound,
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
        payload: notification.body);
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> localNotificationBackground(
    {required NotificationResponse details}) async {
  print(details.payload);
}
```

What I am doing wrong or what I am missing ?

I also have this function for the firebase background notification. Is this the reason ?

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  List<FirebaseApp> app = Firebase.apps;
  if (app.length < 2) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: "xxxxxxxxxx", options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  }
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: true,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: true,
    sound: true,
  );
}
```

Comment: put the navigation logic in firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler.

Comment: if I put the logic in the firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler it will trigger every time I receive the notification right? But the issue is with the `onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:` please take a look at the error or can you explain more clearly. @ManishDayma

Answer (score 0):

In the main function simply replace:

```
onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: (details) =>
        firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,
```

With:

```
onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,
```

This way you directly call the top-level function.

And change the definition of handler from:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
```

To:

```
void firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
  final NotificationResponse details,
) {
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Answering on how to navigate from a Top Level Function:

I made a Singleton which is accesible from Top Level Function. This singleton manages a Stream and emits a new event everytime the user taps on a notification.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:listsapp/common/types/types.dart';

class ActionNotificationService {
  factory ActionNotificationService() => _instance ??= ActionNotificationService._();

  ActionNotificationService._() : _notificationsController = StreamController.broadcast();

  static ActionNotificationService? _instance;
  final StreamController<JSON> _notificationsController;

  void add(JSON payload) => _notificationsController.add(payload);

  Stream<JSON> getNotificationOpenedStream() => _notificationsController.stream;

  void close() {
    _notificationsController.close();
  }
}
```

Inside my app I listen to this stream and navigate to the specific screen.

Also, remember to close the singleton stream when your application doesn't need it no more.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to navigate to a specific screen/page after clicking on a local notification you need to take a look at the method that is called in the `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` parameter of `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(...)`. In these method you can define the navigation.

The method that is called in the `onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse` triggers a background action that does not bring the app to the foreground.

Example:

```
...

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onTapLocalNotification,
);

void onTapLocalNotification(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
        // enter here your screen route name to which you want to navigate, for example
        '/screen',
        )
}
```

For more information about routing or using `Navigator.pushNamed()` have a look at [Flutter navigation and routing here](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation) and [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).